# Angular singleton service

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

From my understanding the only difference between using `providedIn: 'root'` and adding your provider to the `providers` array of the module is for tree shaking.  Currently my application works fine if I add `providedIn: 'root'` it works fine, but if I remove that and add it to the providers array of the module I get the `StaticInjectorError` saying it cant find the provider.  Has anyone seen this or have an understanding of why this would happen? From the docs I believe that adding  it to the providers array should allow this to work

Comment: You need to provide some code, or even better a `stackblitz` example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. IF you do `providedIn: 'root'`, then your service gets registered on the RootInjector. And hence it's basically available to use throughout the App without having to manually add it to the `providers` array of each of the module that you want to use this service in.

But now that you have removed the `providedIn: 'root'` from the `@Injectable` decorator, it will only be available to the Modules where you are adding it to the `providers` array of those modules. Or it would be available to the modules who are importing the modules that have the service added to the `providers` array.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dependency-injection-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to help you understand this in a better way.

Just to describe:

1. I have 3 Modules in there: `AppModule`, `NewModule`, and `NotImportedModule`.
2. I'll be using the services written in the `NewModule` and the `NotImportedModule` in the `AppModule`'s `AppComponent`.
3. `NewModule`'s `SampleService` is added to the `provides` array of the `NewModule` and the `NewModule` is added to the `imports` array of the `AppModule`. And that's why I'm able to use the `SampleService` in the `AppComponent`.
4. `NotImportedModule` is not added to the `imports` array of the `AppModule` but the `AnotherService` is `providedIn: 'root'`. Hence I'm able to use it in the `AppModule`.

Which would mean that `AnotherService` would be available to be used throughout the App since it is registered on the RootInjector, since we used `providedIn: 'root'` on it.

But since `SampleService` was NOT `providedIn: 'root'` but was added to the `providers` array of the `NewModule` to use it in the `AppModule`, we had to add the `NewModule` to the `imports` array of the `AppModule`.

Hope it makes more sense with this example.