# Can't create singleton service in Angular (following the docs)

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, singleton, angular8

I have a service that I wanted to be singleton. According to [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#using-providedin), I need to the *providedIn* as root, which I have done as shown below.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class SecurityService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log("SecServ created.");
  }
}
```

However, every time I navigate to a component that has the service injected, I can see the log in the console telling me that a new instance is created. I tried removing/adding the service in providers section of the module. It was added from start (by the CLI tools) despite it being obsolete approach (according to [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#ngmodule-providers-array)).

**How can I make the service behave as a singleton?**

The only thing I can think of at the moment is to keep a provate reference to the service in the service and make it static and assignable to each new attempt to create an instance. But it seems like a very clunky and hacky way, causing more pain than join.

There's [a deep blog](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/aktuelles/the-new-treeshakable-providers-api-in-angular/) on this subject, confirming my approach (as far I understand, at least). I only have one module (except the routing that doesn't relate to this) so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070689/angular-singleton-service) won't do. Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276223/angular-6-creating-singleton-service) they give the solution to the exact opposite behavior requested, so I'm concluding that my way is the right one if I want the service to be instantiated once and once only but injected in multiple components.

Comment: for a simple test case remove every reference to the service, remove the 'providedIn' and added in your desired module (unless u are using it in your app component) and then finally inject the service inside your component's constructor

Comment: please include an example of how you are injecting the service

Comment: What ever you're doing, it's wrong. We can't tell, though, because the post doesn't have enough information to go on. I put together a quick project to try and repro this,  and the service wasn't recreated during navigation. The singleton worked as expected. Give us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the service to behave as a singleton, it shouldn't be added in any providers section. All you have to do is to import it in any component that its needed.

So just make sure it's not included in any providers.

Comment: Liike I mentioned in the question, I've tried with it both added and commented out in the module file's providers section. I get the same behavior from the app.

Comment: Do a search in the project and find everywhere its referenced. Also what version of angular / angular cli are you using

Comment: Angular 8. There are two spots where I inject it into the constructors.

Comment: the last thing i can think of is to check the imports .. thats its only `import {SecurityService} from './some/path` without any extensions

Comment: If that checks out, try and recreate on stackblitz